# One file per partition (Coalesce per pertition) while inserting data into hive table

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-partitioning, partition-by

I have a table created in hive stored in s3 location.
It has about 10 columns and is partitioned on 3 columns month, year and city , in the same order.

I am running a spark job that creates a dataframe(2 billion rows) and writes into this table.

```
val partitions:Seq[Column] = Seq(col("month"),col("year"),col("city"))
df.repartition(partitions: _*).selectExpr(cs.map(_.name): _*).write.mode("overwrite").insertInto(s"$tableName")
```

selectExpr(cs.map(_.name): _*) reorders the columns in the dataframe to align with the ordering in the table.

When i run the above command to insert into the table, I see there are so many staging files and multiple small files created under each city.

```
s3://s3Root/tableName/month/year/city/file1.csv
                                      file2.csv
                                      ...
                                      file200.csv
```

I am hoping to get a single file under each city per year per month.
***To coalesce per partition.***

Expected:

```
s3://s3Root/tableName/month/year/city/file.csv
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve one file by partition you should use

```
.partitionBy("")

val partitions:Seq[Column] = Seq(col("month"),col("year"),col("city"))

df.repartition(partitions: _*).selectExpr(cs.map(_.name): _*).write.partitionBy(partitions: _*).mode("overwrite").insertInto(s"$tableName")
```

I think that you could avoid to make the repartition before, if you do only the partitionBy,files will be partitioned by one per partition.